# Как задеплоить ftp в Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, ftp, kubernetes

Господа здравствуйте. 2 недели пытаюсь задеплоить в kub ftp
По данной сылке.
 https://github.com/aledv/kubernetes-ftp
Есть проблема захожу по cmd без проблем. Пытаюсь зайти по FileZilla вылетают алерты:

Превышено время ожидания (соединение потока передачи данных)
Не могу получить содержимое каталога
Не могу просмотреть каталог '/'.

Вообщем задаюсь вопросом как задеплоить ftp в kub. Есть ли простые примеры для чайников ?

Comment: А порт 21 открыт?

Comment: Нет просто 20-ый порт работал не стабильно. Из-за него пришлось идти на 21-ый. Я могу путать порты. Обьясню по другому. Проблема была с Пассивным портом. Поэтому юзать пришлось только активный. Трабла связанна была с ftp-клиентом FileZilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае проблема заключалась в том что ftp мог работать только через 21-ый порт. И использование а filezilla было бесмысленным. Открыв WincScp вопрос решился.

Для чайников совет. Вначале киньте в докер, потом можно в куб. так проще.